# Несложная 3D графика в построении пользовательских web интерфейсов

Tags: веб-программирование, gui, 3d

Есть проект в котором нужно отобразить несколько обектов в виде цилиндров с изменением уровня наполнения в реальном времени (такой себе дашборд). Пока лазил в поисках готовых решений наткнулся на `three.js` . Очень мне понравились примеры использования, например https://predictiveworld.watchdogs.com/en/

На сколько оправдано использование 3D технологий подобных `three.js` для построения пользовательских интерфейсов? На сколько сложно их комбинировать с обычной `html` разметкой?

Насколько хорошая/плохая идея совместить `three.js` с `react.js` ?

Answer (score 1):

> На сколько оправдано использование 3D технологий подобных three.js для построения пользовательских интерфейсов?

настолько, насколько полезным окажется `three.js` в вашем проекте, в этой библиотеке уже содержится [готовый функционал](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Geometries/CylinderGeometry) генерирующий достаточно много 3ёх мерных примитивов, включая цилиндр. `three.js` это просто большая упрощённая обёртка над `webgl API`, который достаточно низкоуровненый и следовательно высокопроизводительный, так что если `ui` элементов будет много - то выбирайте её не думая.

> На сколько сложно их комбинировать с обычной html разметкой?

не понятен вопрос честно говоря, зависит от того, что подразумевается под комбинированием, но, во всяком случае `html` рендерится без особых проблем поверх `canvas` элемента.

> Насколько хорошая/плохая идея совместить three.js с react.js ?

я не особо знаком с `react` но так как оба этих фреймворка написаны проповедуя разный стиль программирования, то руками их совмещать было бы довольно неудобно и странно, но существует [байндинг](https://github.com/toxicFork/react-three-renderer) позволяющий использовать `three.js` в стиле `react` - этот проект ещё в стадии разработки, как там говорится, но во всяком случае ознакомится с ним стоит по любому.